# Node.js installation error

Tags: node.js

I tried to install node.js on a Windows 8 machine, but I got the following error:

> The cabinet file 'media1.cab' required for this installation
>   is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an
>   error reading from the the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

I downloaded the installation file from the node.js website at http://nodejs.org/download/.

How I can solve this problem.

> My system specifications are OS  : Windows8 32bit, RAM : 4GB, CPU :
>   Intel Pentium P6200, 2.13Gz, Dual Core

Comment: corrupted download?  perhaps try to download again?

Comment: I downloaded it several times. But for every time it shows the same error. But I installed it in a Windows7 64 bit PC successfully.

Comment: Check for other possiblities : disk error, bad sectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing the same error message trying to install on Windows 7.

I was able to fix this issue and successfully install by:
changing the directory for installation.

Instead of installing within my "**Program Files (X86)**" folder, I installed into my "**Program Files**" folder

My suggestion is to try installing to a different directory as this solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually above none of answers ara not worked for me. I'm using windows 8.1 x64 . So i'm trying install nodejs.msi. Actually i can not install it. So i have used [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) package manager. This is the command that i used for install nodejs. `choco install nodejs.install` Thats all it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling here, my problem (on win 7) was I accidentally downloaded the 32-bit version by mistake. Getting the 64-bit version was the solution.